# Python config parser raises exception for one value but not others

Tags: python, config, configparser

I have the following method:

```
def PopulateStaticDetails(args):
    confParser = ConfigParser.SafeConfigParser()
    confParser.read(args.configFile)

    generator = ''
    emails = ''
    certType = ''

    # ---- Cert Server Check ---- #
    if args.generator is None:
        try: generator = confParser.get('Certificate Generator', 'server').strip()
        except:
            log.fatal('No certificate generator server designated. Please check your configuration.')
            log.fatal('Exiting.')
            exit(1)
    else:
        generator = args.generator

    # ---- Cert Type Check ---- #
    if args.certType is None:
        try: certType = configParser.get('Application Settings', 'cert').strip()
        except:
            print "Unexpected error:", sys.exc_info()[0]
            log.fatal('No certificate type was designated. Please check your configuration.')
            exit(1)
    else:
        certType = args.certType
    if certType not in ('2011', '2013', '2015'):
        log.fatal('Invalid certificate type: {}'.format(certType))
        exit(1)

    # ---- Email List Check ---- #
    if args.emails is None:
        try:
            emails = confParser.get('Application Settings', 'emails').strip().split('\n')
            if emails == ['']: raise
        except:
            log.warn('No email address specified to send results to.')
    else:
        emails = args.emails

    destDir = '{}/{}'.format(args.destdir,certType)
    certPass = getpass.getpass(prompt="Enter your password for access  before proceeding:\n")
    return StaticDetails(generator, args.certuser, certType, certPass, emails, destDir)
```

With the following config:

```
[Application Settings]
servers:
    serv.a.com
    serv.b.com
    serv.c.com

cert: 2015

emails: me@supbro.com
```

I get the following output though:

```
Unexpected error: <type 'exceptions.NameError'>
[2015-04-09 17:43:33,911] | ssl-setup - CRITICAL - No certificate type was designated. Please check your configuration.
```

If I specify it on the command-line, `--cert 2015`, it continues successfully. Why does the `emails:` section work fine, but the `cert:` section doesn't? I'm sure there's something simple here that I've just overlooked ...

Comment: write confParser instead of configParser

Comment: I would also recommend adding `exc_info=True` to the arguments of any logging statements inside exception handlers, unless you're positive the exception is irrelevant to the logged event.  That will print a full traceback so you can debug more easily.  I'm assuming you're using `logging` and not some other logging package.

Comment: Noted, thanks for the tip